# Problems and Inaccuracies Converting + Interpreting Unity Shadergraph to C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, noise, code-translation, shader-graph, shaderlab

### Context

I've been trying to create a buoyancy script that samples the position of a point, tests if it's under a certain level (the *"water level"*), and adds a force on that position based on depth. Separately, I worked on creating a nice looking water shader in Shadergraph, and had the bright idea to add in waves using the Simple Noise node + vertex displacement.

However, the only way (I could think of) to use those displaced values as the float "water level" was to rewrite the entire node tree in C#, and use that to sample the "water level" at that position.

### Problem

For some reason, the final displaced mesh and the calculated positions are different, causing the buoyancy script to assume that the "water level" is higher/lower than it is. The difference isn't large, so I'm assuming there's an error somewhere within either the C# Node Graph or C# Simple Noise translation.

**Is that correct? If so, where and what's my misunderstanding? If not, what else could have gone wrong?**

### Approach

##### Node Graph

[Image of the node graph for the wave vector displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDbyn.png)

**If you need zoomed in pictures, let me know!*

All things considered, it's relatively simple. It:

1. Takes the world position as a UV, and offsets and tiles it.
2. Feeds the UV to a Simple Noise node, and multiplies the noise by a strength.
3. Clamps the output.
4. Repeats 1-3 again and adds both together for more detail.
5. Replaces the Y value of the vertex position with the combined wave value.

##### C# Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveHeightCalculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Step 1
    [SerializeField] Material _waterMaterial;

    [Header("Waves")]
    [SerializeField] float _waveTiling;
    [SerializeField] float _waveOffset;
    [SerializeField] float _waveMin;
    [SerializeField] float _waveMax;
    [Header("Small Waves")]
    [SerializeField] float _wavesSmallScale;
    [SerializeField] float _wavesSmallStrength;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 _wavesSmallVelocity;
    [Header("Large Waves")]
    [SerializeField] float _wavesLargeScale;
    [SerializeField] float _wavesLargeStrength;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 _wavesLargeVelocity;
    
    // Step 2
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        _waterMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
        SetVariables();
    }
    void SetVariables()
    {
        _waveTiling = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Wave_Tiling");
        _waveOffset = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Wave_Offset");
        _waveMin = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Wave_Min");
        _waveMax = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Wave_Max");
        _wavesSmallScale = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Waves_Small_Scale");
        _wavesSmallStrength = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Waves_Small_Strength");
        _wavesSmallVelocity = _waterMaterial.GetVector("_Waves_Small_Velocity");
        _wavesLargeScale = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Waves_Large_Scale");
        _wavesLargeStrength = _waterMaterial.GetFloat("_Waves_Large_Strength");
        _wavesLargeVelocity = _waterMaterial.GetVector("_Waves_Large_Velocity");
    }

    // Step 3
    public float GetWaveHeightAtPosition(Vector3 position)
    {
        Vector2 noiseMapUV;
        noiseMapUV = new Vector2(position.x, position.z) * _waveTiling;
        // Calculate Small Waves
        Vector2 wavesSmallUVOffset = (Time.time / 20) * _wavesSmallVelocity;
        float noiseValueAtUVPlusOffset = UnitySimpleNoiseAtUV(noiseMapUV + wavesSmallUVOffset, _wavesSmallScale);
        float wavesSmall = noiseValueAtUVPlusOffset * _wavesSmallStrength;
        // Calculate Large Waves
        Vector2 wavesLargeUVOffset = (Time.time / 20) * _wavesLargeVelocity;
        noiseValueAtUVPlusOffset = UnitySimpleNoiseAtUV(noiseMapUV + wavesLargeUVOffset, _wavesLargeScale);
        float wavesLarge = noiseValueAtUVPlusOffset * _wavesLargeStrength;
        // Combine
        float waveHeight = wavesSmall + wavesLarge;
        // Clamp
        waveHeight = Mathf.Clamp(waveHeight, _waveMin, _waveMax);
        // Offset
        waveHeight += _waveOffset;
        return waveHeight;
    }
```

In the C# script, a couple of things are going on. Here's my thought process for it:

1. It assigns the relevant material properties to member variables.
2. It sets those variables in the OnValidate() function.
3. **It uses those variables to calculate the wave value; equivalent to the "water level".**

The script also contains and relies on my best attempt at translating the Simple Noise node from "Show Generated Code", which looked liked this.

##### Generated Code

```
inline float Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float (float2 uv)
{
    float angle = dot(uv, float2(12.9898, 78.233));
    #if defined(SHADER_API_MOBILE) && (defined(SHADER_API_GLES) || defined(SHADER_API_GLES3) || defined(SHADER_API_VULKAN))
        // 'sin()' has bad precision on Mali GPUs for inputs > 10000
        angle = fmod(angle, TWO_PI); // Avoid large inputs to sin()
    #endif
    return frac(sin(angle)*43758.5453);
}

inline float Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float (float a, float b, float t)
{
    return (1.0-t)*a + (t*b);
}


inline float Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float (float2 uv)
{
    float2 i = floor(uv);
    float2 f = frac(uv);
    f = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    uv = abs(frac(uv) - 0.5);
    float2 c0 = i + float2(0.0, 0.0);
    float2 c1 = i + float2(1.0, 0.0);
    float2 c2 = i + float2(0.0, 1.0);
    float2 c3 = i + float2(1.0, 1.0);
    float r0 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c0);
    float r1 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c1);
    float r2 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c2);
    float r3 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c3);

    float bottomOfGrid = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(r0, r1, f.x);
    float topOfGrid = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(r2, r3, f.x);
    float t = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(bottomOfGrid, topOfGrid, f.y);
    return t;
}
void Unity_SimpleNoise_float(float2 UV, float Scale, out float Out)
{
    float t = 0.0;

    float freq = pow(2.0, float(0));
    float amp = pow(0.5, float(3-0));
    t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(float2(UV.x*Scale/freq, UV.y*Scale/freq))*amp;

    freq = pow(2.0, float(1));
    amp = pow(0.5, float(3-1));
    t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(float2(UV.x*Scale/freq, UV.y*Scale/freq))*amp;

    freq = pow(2.0, float(2));
    amp = pow(0.5, float(3-2));
    t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(float2(UV.x*Scale/freq, UV.y*Scale/freq))*amp;

    Out = t;
}

    /* WARNING: $splice Could not find named fragment 'CustomInterpolatorPreVertex' */

    // Graph Vertex
    // GraphVertex: <None>

    /* WARNING: $splice Could not find named fragment 'CustomInterpolatorPreSurface' */

    // Graph Pixel
    struct SurfaceDescription
{
float4 Out;
};
```

##### Translated Code

```
    float float_frac(float x) { return x - Mathf.Floor(x);}
    Vector2 frac(Vector2 x) { return x - new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(x.x), Mathf.Floor(x.y));}
    float sin(float x) { return Mathf.Sin(x);}
    float dot(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) { return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;}
    float float_floor(float x) { return Mathf.Floor(x);}
    Vector2 floor(Vector2 x) { return new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(x.x), Mathf.Floor(x.y));}
    float float_abs(float x) { return Mathf.Abs(x);}
    Vector2 abs(Vector2 x) { return new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(x.x), Mathf.Abs(x.y));}
    float pow (float x, float y) { return Mathf.Pow(x, y);}

    float Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float (Vector2 uv)
    {
        float angle = dot(uv, new Vector2(12.9898f, 78.233f));
        return float_frac(sin(angle) * 43758.5453f);
    }
    float Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float (float a, float b, float t)
    {
        return (1.0f - t) * a + (t * b);
    }
    float Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float (Vector2 uv)
    {
        Vector2 i = floor(uv);
        Vector2 f = frac(uv);
        f = (f * f) * (new Vector2 (3.0f, 3.0f) - new Vector2(2.0f, 2.0f) * f);

        uv = abs(frac(uv) - new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f));
        Vector2 c0 = i + new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector2 c1 = i + new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector2 c2 = i + new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector2 c3 = i + new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);
        float r0 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c0);
        float r1 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c1);
        float r2 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c2);
        float r3 = Unity_SimpleNoise_RandomValue_float(c3);

        float bottomOfGrid = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(r0, r1, f.x);
        float topOfGrid = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(r2, r3, f.x);
        float t = Unity_SimpleNnoise_Interpolate_float(bottomOfGrid, topOfGrid, f.y);
        return t;
    }
    float UnitySimpleNoiseAtUV(Vector2 UV, float Scale)
    {
        float t = 0.0f;

        float freq = pow(2.0f, 0);
        float amp = pow(0.5f, 3-0);
        t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(new Vector2(UV.x*Scale/freq, UV.y*Scale/freq))*amp;

        freq = pow(2.0f, 1);
        amp = pow(0.5f, 3-1);
        t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(new Vector2(UV.x * Scale / freq, UV.y * Scale / freq)) * amp;

        freq = pow(2.0f, 2);
        amp = pow(0.5f, 3-2);
        t += Unity_SimpleNoise_ValueNoise_float(new Vector2(UV.x * Scale / freq, UV.y * Scale / freq)) * amp;

        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same premise as you, and in fact used your translation of the simple noise node to get my calculation working.

Here's a few things I did differently that might have caused the calculation difference.

I used Time.timeSinceLevelLoad rather than Time.time, as that's the one that the shader graph apparently uses as well (See [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-_time-y-equal-to-time-time-on-the-cpu-or-are-they-not-in-sync.739499/)). Using Time.time may have caused some values to differ between frames so that might be the cause of some discrepancy.

I also used TransformPoint on the final Y coordinate I got in order to use the world coordinate of my water plane's vertex rather than its local coordinate. With my plane at (0,0,0), the shader causes the local y-value of the wave in the plane to be around y = 0.6, but in world space that y-value is actually around y=5.9 instead. So I needed that transformation as otherwise it give me the water plane's local height.

Here's my water height function, using shader from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbTAbOnhRcI).

```
public float GetWaterHeight(Vector3 position)
{
    //need to do the shader's y position calculation to get the height of the vertex at this position
    var uvInput = waveTile * (waveTileFactor * (new Vector2(position.x, position.z)));
    Debug.Log("Uv Input: " + uvInput);
    var offsetInput = waveSpeed * ((Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * new Vector2(0, 1)) / 20);
    Debug.Log("Offset Input: " + offsetInput + " with time as " + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
    var tilingOutput = uvInput * new Vector2(1, 1) + offsetInput;
    var noiseOutput = UnitySimpleNoiseAtUV(tilingOutput, waveScale);
    Debug.Log("Noise gen: " + noiseOutput + " from tilingOutput " + tilingOutput);
    var finalY = waveStrength * noiseOutput;

    //var pixelValue = oceanTex.GetPixelBilinear(transform.position.y, transform.position.z).b;
    return ocean.position.y + ocean.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, finalY, 0)).y;
}
```

The rest of the code (for the simple noise function and whatnot) is the same as yours.